# How to parse HIPAA 834 EDI File and generate 997 using python?

Tags: python, edi, x12

I have to parse and validate HIPAA 834 EDI file and generate 997 response with the success or error message

Sample 834 EDI File:

ISA*00*          *00*          *30*261401960      *30*261105741 *210525*0609*^*00501*189171275*0*T*:~

GS*BE*161401960*Facets*20210525*0609*171275*X*005010X220A1~

ST*834*0001*005010X220A1~

REF*38*00417558~

QTY*DT*958~

QTY**1381~

QTY**1381~

N1*IN*HealthPLAN *FI*161105741~

INS*Y*18*030*XN*A***AC*N*N~

F*0F*951747732~

REF*1L*00417558~

REF*17*0001~

REF*DX*0001~

DTP*336*D8*20040202~

PER*IP**EM*mvastola@wscschools.org*HP*7169543565~

N3*130 Rosewood Dr.~

N4*West Seneca*NY*14224~

DMG*D8*19810817*M*M~

HD*024**HLT*CPO1Y000*FAM~

INS*Y*18*030*XN*A***AC*N*N~

DTP*303*D8*20200701~

INS*N*01*030*XN*A****N*N~

REF*0F*951747732~

REF*1L*00417558~

REF*17*0001~

REF*DX*0001~

NM1*IL*1*Testmember*Jessica****34*962703984~

N3*130 Rosewood Dr.~

N4*West Seneca*NY*14224~

DMG*D8*19820720*F~

HD*024**HLT*CPO1Y000*FAM~

DTP*303*D8*20200701~

DTP*348*D8*20200701~

INS*N*19*030*XN*A****F*N~

REF*0F*951747732~

REF*1L*00417558~

REF*17*0001~ REF*DX*0001~

NM1*IL*1*testy*Sofia****34*992599285~

N3*130 Rosewood Dr.~

N4*West Seneca*NY*14224~

DMG*D8*20120524*F~

HD*030**HLT*CPO1Y000*FAM~

DTP*303*D8*20200701~

DTP*348*D8*20200701~

SE*47*0001~

GE*1*171275~

IEA*1*189171275~

please help me out to resolve the issue, I'm not understanding how to use pyx12 parser library which is available in python or implement the code using pyx12

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've lost a bit of your formatting.

The ~ is the segment terminator.  The * character is the element separator.  So you should first split by the segment end, read each segment in, and then parse each element.

There is the concept of qualifiers, backed by a dictionary.  The N1 segment typically holds names, with N3 and N4 being address segments.  The first element in the N1 segment (N101) is a qualifier. It describes the data in the N102 using a code value.  The 834 has many of these.

REF*17*0001~
REF*DX*0001~

In this case 17 and DX describe what value is in the REF02.

You should download a tool like EDI Notepad so that you can understand what each element is, what it means and how to parse it into something your application can understand.

Comment: Once you follow Andrew's advice above and get the EDI file properly formatted, if you want to parse this document and understand the semantics without downloading any software, you can use Stedi's EDI Inspector tool: https://edi.stedi.com/inspector. Just copy paste the EDI file on the left, and select "JSON" view on the right hand side. If you file is invalid, it will provide you with validation errors and recommendations.